# Adding Windows Form Functionality on ASP.NET (VB) Web Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have been building a Web Application (ASP.NET, .NET Framework 4, VB, visual studio 2010). To be very brief the application interacts with a database and performs several actions (Insert Delete Select etc..).

I am using several Gridviews, ListBoxes etc and I am not happy with the presentation outcome and the functionality provided by asp.net. In simple words my application looks bad, outdated and unprofessional.
I figured that using Windows Forms that will be incorporated to the ASP app would be a great improvement and solve all of my problems.

I have created a Windows Form Control Library to use the dll created in my app as a user control. I found out that this is not supported in .NET Framework 4 (is this true? or am i doing something wrong?).

Is there any way to make my application have the 'look and feel' of a windows application? 
Please note that it is has to be a web app and the clients should not have to download any other application to interact with the server.

Comment: Wow! You sure _are_ lost. Windows Forms and ASP.NET are mutually exclusive. You can't really use them together, and your supervisor doesn't want you to. Most likely, you should learn how to make ASP.NET applications look better instead of giving up.

Comment: John I am not a student and dont have a supervisor. I am an electrical engineer building a whole system part of which is this appliccation..I know my background is not a programming one but i am a quick learner. Anyways, thank you for your reply.

Comment: I didn't say you are a student. As an engineer, you must understand the importance of learning _how things work_. You need to take the time to understand the difference between ASP.NET and Windows Forms.

Comment: Well this is exactly what I am doing. But i have seen that with .NET Framework 2 one could create a Windows Form Library, take the created dll and use it in an ASP.NET application as an object.. Hence my question about windows forms and ASP.NET.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood. There is no way to create a Windows Forms library and use it _as Windows Forms controls_ within an ASP.NET application. There is an old hack for displaying Windows Forms controls within Internet Explorer, but it doesn't work for other browsers, and is a really bad idea. You're better off learning how to make web applications that look professional.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the third party controls from other vendors?

I currently use them for rapid development.

http://www.telerik.com/

http://www.infragistics.com/

http://www.devexpress.com/

Anyhow all controls in .net you can change there look and feel using plain CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Silverlight 4, it has all that you need. What u are trying to do is traditional ASP.NET and that's as good as it can get coz its all server side code, but with Silverlight things are totally different, its all client side with specific server interactions. Have a look at the tutorials about how to use Silverlight and WCF RIA services to do what you are trying to do.

Try this link: [WCF RIA services and Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services)

Edit: Silverlight is designed to create stunning web GUIs. Just in case you were wondering what the heck it is.. :)

Comment: I know what it is (although very little), but while i was researching i have seen references saying that Silverlight is not widely used anymore and that Microsoft has abandoned it..Probably am mistaken. Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say Microsoft has abandoned it, infact RC5 is just out. As long as you don't see "Abandoned-out of business, sorry" on MS' official website, don't believe word of the mouth and don't worry :) . Its just that only people who don't want their users having to install a plugin to view their websites, instigate such rumours. In some sense its OK, nothing beats a simple yet effective web design but Silverlight is not all about eye candy, as you will see when you delve deeper yourself.

Comment: Haaha..Fair enough. Will look into Silverlight. Cheers